# How to compare Dynamic Range of two images

Tags: camera

I am trying to compare two cameras and their WDR.

The first picture is taken with a Oak-D camera and the second one is taken with an iPhone11

[image: oak-d camera][image]

Upon visual inspection it is obvious that the iPhone camera has a much better quality in the colors. But some of the other cameras I'm trying to compare are much harder to tell, so I want to quantify it numerically.

How do I prove with numbers which image quality is better?

Answer (score 0):

Blind image quality assessment will work out for you. It is the process of analyzing the quality of a given image without a reference image. There are bundles of pre-trained networks ([API](https://github.com/ocampor/image-quality), [Code](https://github.com/h4nwei/SPAQ)) available that will quantitively analyze your image.